# React - dynamically update UI based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, radio-button

**Question**

I'm working on a web application feature that calculates the heat insulation factor for a specific area. You can check out the live Codesandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/cloudmako09/btu-calc/main?import=true&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qu0007356mdmjohkm1%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0003356m9a2pbp96%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0005356m2fhlmjgh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0006356m59g30n2b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60%252C40%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clnd9z7qt0003356m9a2pbp96%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0003356m9a2pbp96%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FinsulFactor%252FinsulFactor.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnda2x2a00qc356mtj2e47y4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnda2x2a00qc356mtj2e47y4%2522%257D%252C%2522clnd9z7qt0006356m59g30n2b%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0006356m59g30n2b%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnd9znzc00as356m67b5lk67%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9znzc00as356m67b5lk67%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clnd9z7qt0005356m2fhlmjgh%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0005356m2fhlmjgh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0004356mqlenn64j%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9z7qt0004356mqlenn64j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clnda596h0019e5d93j2j98k4%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clnd9zl8i0099356mh5wsd67h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) (it's the third red area with the radio buttons).

The issue I'm facing is that when a user clicks on a radio button, I can see in the console logs that the state updates correctly. However, the "Factor" box on the right side of the page doesn't consistently update when a user clicks on a radio button. I'd like it to update every time a radio button is clicked. How can I achieve this?

**Insulation Factor component:**

```
export const InsulFactor = () => {
  // Pull in state from Zustand global store
  const {
    insul,
    wellInsul,
    poorlyInsul,
    notInsul,
    setInsul,
    setWellInsul,
    setPoorlyInsul,
    setNotInsul,
  } = useInsulFactorStore();

  const handleInsulChange = () => {
    setInsul(2);
  };

  const handleWellInsulChange = () => {
    setWellInsul(4);
  };

  const handlePoorlyInsulChange = () => {
    setPoorlyInsul(7);
  };

  const handleNotInsulChange = () => {
    setNotInsul(8.5);
  };

  const getInsulFactor = () => {
    if (insul) {
      return insul;
    }
    if (wellInsul) {
      return wellInsul;
    }
    if (poorlyInsul) {
      return poorlyInsul;
    }
    if (notInsul) {
      return notInsul;
    }
    return insul;
  };

  return (
    <>
     ...
          <Row>
            <Col lg="4">
              <CheckBox
                heading="Insulated"
                desc="Enclosed area with doors and windows in place."
                id="insulated"
                name="insulation"
                checked={insul === 2}
                onChange={handleInsulChange}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col lg="4">
              <CheckBox
                heading="Well Insulated"
                desc="Sealed environment. Walls constructed but lacking insulation. Doors and windows shielded with plastic sheets or tarps."
                id="well-insulated"
                name="insulation"
                checked={wellInsul === 4}
                onChange={handleWellInsulChange}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col lg="4">&nbsp;</Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="4">
              <CheckBox
                heading="Poorly Insulated"
                desc="Semi-enclosed area with numerous walls in place."
                id="poorly-insulated"
                name="insulation"
                checked={poorlyInsul === 7.5}
                onChange={handlePoorlyInsulChange}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col lg="4">
              <CheckBox
                heading="Not Insulated"
                desc="Uncovered area with primary walls not yet built."
                id="not-insulated"
                name="insulation"
                checked={notInsul === 8}
                onChange={handleNotInsulChange}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col lg="4">
              <Result heading="Factor" number={getInsulFactor()} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        ...
    </>
  );
};
```

**Radio component:**

```
export const CheckBox: React.FC<Props> = ({
  heading,
  desc,
  id,
  name,
  onChange,
  checked,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Check
          type="radio"
          label=""
          id={id}
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          defaultChecked={checked}
        />
        <h3>{heading}</h3>
        <p>{desc}</p>
      </Form.Group>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the code I think the issue is in the `useInsulFactorStore` You have multiple levels of `insul` which then conflict with each other as your `getInsulFactor` function will return the first truthy value.

Instead, you should change your context to only have one `insul/setInsul` state that then updates depending on the selected option.
I made some edits to the [CodeSandBox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/cloudmako09/btu-calc/csb-3793dt/draft/long-mountain) with these changes so you can check it out.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your solution works!